# Python - Como printar varias variáveis em loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou coletando 7 valores diferente através de um `while`. Toda vez que o `while` roda, um valor é atribuído a variável `valor` e é `printado`, mas gostaria de salvar cada `valor` em uma variável para utilizar posteriormente.

Por exemplo, o primeiro print, `var1 = valor`, na segunda vez, `var2 = valor`, na terceira vez, `var3 = valor`...

Comment: Primeiro precisa decidir se vai imprimir ou se vai atribuir um valor.

Comment: Armazena os valores lidos em uma lista. Pode definir `valor = []` e dentro do while fazer: `valor.append()` para adicionar o novo valor na lista, assim cada valor será armazenado em um índice diferente e poderá ser utilizado posteriormente.

Comment: Olá Anderson, obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou muito bem!

Você saberia me dizer como posso transformar a string em um inteiro?
Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém esteja na mesma situação:

Como o Anderson Carlos Woss explicou acima, crie uma `lista` e utilize o `lista.append(objeto)` para colocar os valores na lista.

Caso queira repassar para uma variável, defina a `variavel = lista[posição]`.

Caso seus valores sejam do tipo `string`, e deseje transformar em `inteiro`, ao definir a `variavel`, faça: `variavel = int(lista[posição])`.

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram!

Answer (score -2):

Caso queira criar variáveis dinâmicas, ou seja, variáveis que são criadas no momento em que uma estrutura de repetição é executada, podemos utilizar o locals(),
é uma função interna do python que trará um dicionário.

**Veja este código:**

```
for i in range(3):
    locals()[f"var{i}"] = i
    print(f"var{i} = {locals()[f'var{i}']}")
```

**Saída:**

```
var0 = 0
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
```